# Divide each value by its group's average

Tags: python, pandas, scala, pyspark

In pyspark how to create a second column where each value of first column  is divided by its group's average?

That means that you do some average grouping by another column and then divide  each value by the average of its group.

But when grouping you loose rows so it problematic.  How do I solve  it?
Example:

```
Name value 
A    5
B    1
A    3
A    4
B    1
```

I want to achieve  this new df

```
Name value  result
A    5      5/4
B    1      1
A    3      3/4
A    4      1
B    1      1
```

Because the averages of groups A and B are 4 and 1 respectively.

Comment: "do some grouping by another column and then devide each value " -- great plan! Do that :)

Comment: Not good because  when you group  you lose all the rows. I need for each value have another corresponding  value which is the previous  value devided by its group's avg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function. Be careful of divide by zero.

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from math import nan
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

list = [('A', 5), ('B', 1), ('A', 3), ('A', 4), ('B', 1), ('C', 0)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(list, ['name', 'value'])
df.withColumn("avg", func.avg(df["value"]).over(Window.partitionBy(df["name"]))) \
  .withColumn("result", func.col("value") / func.col("avg")) \
  .drop("avg") \
  .show()
```

```
+----+-----+------+
|name|value|result|
+----+-----+------+
|   A|    5|  1.25|
|   A|    3|  0.75|
|   A|    4|   1.0|
|   B|    1|   1.0|
|   B|    1|   1.0|
|   C|    0|  null|
+----+-----+------+
```